# Show All with Isotope

Tags: wp-query, ajax

I'm using Isotpope Filtering (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html) for our new news page and it works great. However, it doesn't allow for pagination (since I'm filtering by categories). Right now, I'm pulling in 500 stories which is much more than I want to on the initial page load (although I'm using ImagesLoaded help on the page load). My thought was to only pull in 20-40 and then have a Load All button that would change the query to be 500.

This seems like a really simple task with Ajax - but I'm struggling to find an example (rather than the common pagination ajax example).  So, what is the best way to make an ajax call to change the wp_query from 20 to 500 and retrigger isotope?

Comment: This question is not WP related, but the basic idea is to load the initial 20 items, and initialize isotope on those items. Add a button at the bottom that makes the ajax request to get more items, update the items loaded to the template, and then tell isotope (reinit) that there are more items to be sorted. This way, Isotope will know of the new items. However, this still only allows you to sort elements that have been loaded. Another option is to save the query result as a transient, so that you only query the results once every set time.

Comment: Did you figure this one out @rmlumley ?

Comment: Not really. I just ended up having all of them load immediately and then I'm loading images on scroll: https://morgridge.org/news/